# method does not work after publication (asp.net-core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a method that does not work after publication on Windows Server 2016.

ASP.NET CORE 2.0 - MVC

Publish method: File system.

So my reputation is low and i cant added image...

I have DataBase with table:

```
 ETP_Main (ETP_MainId , ..., ... )
 ETP_Title (ETP_TitleId, ETP_MainId, ..., ... )
 and etc.
```

Structure my project:

Page:

View Index (have some links)

```
<a asp-action="ControlPage" asp-route-
id="ETP_MainId"></a>
```

View ControlPage

```
 @model GiproApp.Models.Repository.ViewModel                    

<form asp-action="CreateWordFile" asp-route-id="@Model.Mains.ETP_MainId">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Dowload">
</form> 

//***code***
```

i have one controller:

```
namespace GiproApp.Controllers
{
   public class ETPController : Controller
   {
      private readonly DataBaseContext _context;
   }

   //***code*** 

   [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ControlPage(int id)
    {
        ETP_Main main = await _context.ETP_Mains.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ETP_MainId == id);
   //***code***
    }
```

---

**Does not work method CreateWordFile**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateWordFile(int id)
{
   ETP_Main main = await _context.ETP_Mains.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ETP_MainId == id);

   var webRoot = _env.WebRootPath;
   var pathEtp = Path.Combine(webRoot, "files", "Etp.docx");
   var pathDoc = Path.Combine(webRoot, "files", "Doc.docx");

   using (WordprocessingDocument wEtp = WordprocessingDocument.Open(pathEtp, true))
   {
       string docText = null;

       using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wEtp.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
       {
           docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
           sr.Close();
       }

       if (title.ObjName != null) docText = Regex.Replace(docText, "AKEY0", title.ObjName);
            else docText = Regex.Replace(docText, "AKEY0", " ");
                //***code***


       using (WordprocessingDocument wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(pathDoc, true))
       {
           using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
           {
               sw.Write(docText);
               sw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Dowload));
    }
```

---

method Dowload work.

```
    [HttpPost]    
    public IActionResult Dowload()
    {
        var webRoot = _env.WebRootPath;
        var pathDoc = Path.Combine(webRoot, "files", "Doc.docx");
        return base.PhysicalFile(pathDoc, "application/msword", "Doc.docx");
    }
```

error:

```
http://192.168.0.158/ETP/CreateWordFile/30 
HTTP 404 NOT FOUND
```

It should not refer to: CreateWordFile/30

It should download the file.

my NuGet:

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml
jQuery
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
```

When I run the program on the local machine it all works.
Why does not work after publication?

Comment: Controller action configured for POST action so browsing URL directly in browser will return 404 coz it looks for the GET action which I can't find

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya 
I haven't GET action, I have a view and a button on it. I need to read / write and download the file.

Comment: Set method="post" for the form in html.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I added method="post" and republished:

<form method="post" asp-action="CreateWordFile" asp-route-id="@Model.Mains.ETP_MainId">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Dowload"
</form>

Error the same:
http://192.168.0.158/ETP/CreateWordFile/30  
HTTP 404 NOT FOUND

Comment: A few questions. What is the Controller name? is it API controller or MVC Controller? Is the view belong to the same controller? What value you have in `@Model.Mains.ETP_MainId` ? What if you remove `asp-route-id="@Model.Mains.ETP_MainId"` form the form?

Comment: The input tag `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Dowload"` is **not closed** (it needs `></input>`). Is that a typo in your question or your actual code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I added more information.
And I have one controller in project. It's MVC Controller. If i remove route-id="@Model.Mains.ETP_MainId" i will cant replace text.

Comment: @NightOwl888 
it's a typo. Corrected.

Comment: @NightOwl888 In HTML, the <input> tag has no end tag.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: @Дмитрий - Thanks for the correction. It still needed a closing angle bracket `>` to be technically correct, although I suppose most HTML interpreters are probably smart enough to add one automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the properties of the docx file. In properties, set the write permission to read to all users. After that, everything worked.

Comment: https://ru.wikihow.com/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%27%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%27-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-MS-Word